# R code: finding similar matches with a specified accuracy

Tags: r, character, match

I have two tables, and each contains a character variable, for instance in table g1 I have var1 with values such as 'girls leggings', 'leggings', 'leginggs', 'tops', and in g2 I have var2 with values 'girls tops', 'tops', 'leggings', 'long leggings'.
I am trying to compare these character  values  from two tables and based on accuracy match the rows which have  the  highest accuracy match

I thought I can use one to many merge and then just keep the records with the highest match, something like

g$comp<-levenshteinSim(g$var1, g$var2)

for each var1 to all var2 and then pick the row with the highest g$comp.
But since the table is  quite large, the one to many merge can result in really massive data set.
I wonder if there is a way to use the R loop process? Just can't imagine any more elegant and faster way of approaching this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I might consider using the `sqldf` package and using the `LIKE` wildcard to find matches.

Comment: But sqldf helps to extrack back and forth to SQL, if I remember correctly. I am running everything in R. And I don't think Like statement will be sufficient, I really need to see the accuracy score. but thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

you may use lapply function together with agrep (approximate grep) which is fuzzy string matching, it's base r; for my needs, this worked better than `library(stringi)` which you may also explore

```
lapply(g$var1, agrep, x=g$var2, max.distance=0.05, value=T)
```

Comment: Thank you Elio, I am checking this function. It certainly does look like what I need. The output is a list though. It doesn't help to merge to datasets though. Or am I missing something? (sorry, I am not really a programmer)

Comment: make a new column in your data set: g$approximate <- lapply(g$var1, etc)... then you may merge() or left_join() to your other data frame, the one with correct values

Comment: That's what I tried to do in the first place, and got the error:  g$test<- lapply(g$var1, agrep, x=g$var2, max.distance=0.05, value=T)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, test, value = list()) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6

Comment: try agrepl instead

Comment: if you get more than a match per record, you have to flatten your column (or tweak your max.distance), g$approximate <- vapply(g$approximate, paste, collapse=", ", character(1L))

Comment: Same story:  g$test<- lapply(g$var1, agrepl, x=g$var2, max.distance=0.05, value=T)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, test, value = list()) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> obviously there is something I am doing wrong. I am trying to investigate these functions.

Comment: I don't get the error; g <- data.frame(g1=c('girls leggings', 'leggings', 'leginggs', 'tops'),
g2=c('girls tops', 'tops', 'leggings', 'long leggings'))
g$appr <- lapply(g$g1, agrep, g$g2, max.distance=0.25, value=T)
g$appr <- vapply(g$appr, paste, collapse=", ", character(1L))
g

Comment: You are right, I am not getting an error now too. No results either, but it's probably due to high max.distance. I'll need to test it on the larger dataset. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(RecordLinkage)

tbl1 <- data_frame(var1 = c('girls leggings', 'leggings', 'leginggs', 'tops'),
                   var2 = c('girls tops', 'tops', 'leggings', 'long leggings'))


cross2(.x = tbl1$var1, .y = tbl1$var2, .filter = ~levenshteinSim(.x, .y) < 0.4) %>% 
  map(set_names, c("var1", "var2")) %>% bind_rows()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
           var1          var2
          <chr>         <chr>
  1 girls leggings    girls tops
  2           tops    girls tops
  3           tops          tops
  4 girls leggings      leggings
  5       leggings      leggings
  6       leginggs      leggings
  7 girls leggings long leggings
  8       leggings long leggings
  9       leginggs long leggings
```